# How to pass values from on component to Redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am using Redux form for form in React.js and my form was and I have a custom google map component I want to bind lat and long to my form

**form**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
const SimpleForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="position-relative form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="firstName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
<Field name = 'eventLocation'
        component = {MyParentComponentWrapper} />
</form>
  );
};
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple', // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);
```

**and my MyParentComponentWrapper code was**

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withProps, lifecycle } from 'recompose';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL:
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCYSleVFeEf3RR8NlBy2_PzHECzPFFdEP0&libraries=geometry,drawing,places',
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    lifecycle({
        componentWillMount() {
            const refs = {};

            this.setState({
                position: null,
                onMarkerMounted: ref => {
                    refs.marker = ref;
                },

                onPositionChanged: () => {
                    const position = refs.marker.getPosition();
                    console.log(position.toString());
                },
            });
        },
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)(props => (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
        {props.isMarkerShown && (
            <Marker
                position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
                draggable={true}
                ref={props.onMarkerMounted}
                onPositionChanged={props.onPositionChanged}
            />
        )}
    </GoogleMap>
));

class MyParentComponentWrapper extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {
        isMarkerShown: false,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyMapComponent isMarkerShown={true} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyParentComponentWrapper;
```

**this component will console.log the lat and long values when user drag the marker**

How to pass the `console.log` value to redux-form?

Can anyone please suggest a way to do so?

Comment: Instead of getting the logged value, you could not log it and then save it in some variable or state object.

Comment: Create Field with Component wich will be GoogleMap

Comment: i created google map Component but i can"t able to pass the value to redux-form ., my google map Component  code https://codesandbox.io/s/nkvjyppzom

Comment: You should put `position` in your store and pass it into your form as a `prop`, then just set the `value` prop on the field.

Comment: exactly i want that .,can you show a sample code in sandbox.io ?

Comment: Sure. Could you add your form (and its implementation) on your sandbox.io example? I'm not sure where your form is being included here.

Comment: @User_3535 I've forked your initial sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkn6rkmwvv) with what I believe you may be trying to do. Keep in mind, this solution does not use `reduxForm`.

Comment: my simple redux form ., https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp., i want to implement this map component https://codesandbox.io/s/kkn6rkmwvv to redux form

Comment: @User_3535 You have not set up your app to support Redux, and therefore cannot use `redux-form`. If you want to see an example of how this works without Redux, then you can look at the codesandbox that I have created [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkn6rkmwvv).

Comment: take a look at this i implemented your map component to redux form but i can"t able to get values in redux form https://codesandbox.io/s/nkploj0nw0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vnzjx7lnr7) is a codesandbox of your app using a `redux-form`. Notice that after setting up the form in `latLngForm.js`, I use `connect` in your map container to `dispatch` reduxForm's `change` action when your marker is moved. This is what updates the store.

I also pass `position` in as a `prop` to `<MyMapComponent />` to set the position of your marker. This means that your marker's position is always based off of the form's values, and that moving the map's markers manually changes the form's value. This will allow you to set the position manually via the fields, or by dragging and dropping the marker.

`mapStateToProps` in the `<MyMapComponent />` is the important piece here. `redux-form` automatically stores the values in the state for us, this is where we retrieve it.

Notice these lines at the top of the file:

```
import { change, formValueSelector } from "redux-form";
...
const formSelector = formValueSelector("form");
```

This sets up our form selector. `"form"` being the identifier for the form. Now, to retrieve these values from our state, we do:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    position: {
        lat: formSelector(state, 'lat'),
        lng: formSelector(state, 'lng') // The key here is the name you passed into the field.
    }
});
```

Then we use `connect` to actually connect the component to the store:

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(MyMapComponent);
```

Redux does its magic and now our fields are available via `this.props.position` in our component!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo14pk18jp) is my working solution, forked from your sandbox.

I just added a callback in your `MyParentComponentWrapper` component which is fired every time the marker position changes. In your form, you listen to the callback and set the `position` field with the value received from `MyParentComponentWrapper`.

I like to keep components as simpler as possible and not to connect them with redux state via `connect`. Just think of your `MyParentComponentWrapper` as an input field which only fires `change` event every time its value changes without being aware of how/where this value will be used.

In this case `MyParentComponentWrapper` just show a marker and invokes a callback every time marker position changes. It's the form component the one in charge of handling this position in the proper way.

Here's the how I changed your form render with the callback:

`<MyParentComponentWrapper setPosition={onPositionSet} />`

and here's the callback in your form component:

```
const onPositionSet = (position) => {
    props.change("position", position);
}
```

where `change` function has been added to your component props as you wrapped it in a `redux-form`

Answer (score 0):

For functional components you can do this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(change("travellerDetailsForm", "dob", "DD/MM/YYYY"));
    },[])
```

or you can do it in the change handler with the event too like this-

```
  const panNameChangeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const panName = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    dispatch(change("travellerDetailsForm", "name", panName));
  };
```